# CSS ellipsis on text when resizing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<table>` with width set to 100%. Inside the `<td>` is a div with a text string that I want to add an ellipsis to if the width of text overflows.

In the javascript I set the width of the `<div>` to the width of the `<td>` and this works fine on load (or refresh) but I cannot get it to work `onresize`.

(don't worry about what I am actually doing here. It's part of a bigger table I've simplified for the sake of this question.)

Can anyone advise how I can get the text to ellipsis-ify `onresize`?

```js
function doThis() {
    $('.divClass').css('width', $(".tdClass").css('width'));
}
```

```css
.divClass {
    width:0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="doThis()" onresize="doThis()">

<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="tdClass">
            <div class="divClass">
                the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind **resize** with browser's window if not working on body attribute

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   doThis()
});
```

Comment: Have you check whether `doThis` function fired or not on resize?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can be done using only css. 
can you please try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
   /* Added new style property */
table,tr,td,tbody{
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;

}
td{
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
  /* New style property end her */
</style>

</head>
<body>  <!-- //removed onload & onresize -->

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>  <!-- // removed the div -->
             the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works with a single TD per TR but I have other TDs in each data row, so the `inline-block` makes the TDs stack instead of sitting side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

Div is block element, so if you don't give any width, it will automatically take width of td. Means no script is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make table responsive with `display:block` property so that `div` can get proper width from `td` element on resize.

```
table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This works with a single TD per TR but I have other TDs in each data row, so the `inline-block` makes the TDs stack instead of sitting side-by-side.